# Jasmine unit testing directives with external dependencies fails with TypeError: '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm getting an error from my spec when I run it. I'm testing a directive that includes [this service](https://github.com/marklagendijk/angular-recursion). The test is returning an error message:

> TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'angular('RecursionHelper')').

Not sure what I'm missing in order for this to work. I'm using Angular 1.3 & Jasmine 2.0.

my directive:

```
return RecursionHelper.compile(element, function (scope, Element, Attrs,     contro, transFn) {
   //directive functions
});
```

My spec:

```
   beforeEach(function () {
       angular('RecursionHelper');
   });

  element = angular.element('<directive></directive>');
            $scope.directiveList = directiveList;
            RecursionHelper.compile(element)($scope);
            $scope.$digest();
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be contro or control

Comment: Hi Manu, contro, is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `beforeEach` block, you should load your app module, which contains the directive. Change:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular('RecursionHelper');
});
```

To:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('MyApp'); //change to your application name. 
});
```

Also, you should inject `$compile` service and `$rootScope` before each jasmine test. You are using `compile` service to render the directive without injecting it.

Just add to your `beforeEach`:

```
inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $injector) {
    compile = $compile;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
});
```

Final code should look like:

```
   beforeEach(function () {
       module('MyApp'); //change to your application name.
       inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $injector) {
           compile = $compile;
           $scope = $rootScope.$new();
       }); 
   });    


it('make an assertion', function() {
    var element = angular.element('<directive></directive>');
    $scope.directiveList = directiveList;
    compiledElement = compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering my question. It's really close. I've made the adjustments. I get the error:  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'RecursionHelper.compile')

Comment: Pay attention, that I've removed this line `RecursionHelper.compile(element)($scope);` and added `compiledElement = compile(element)($scope);`

Comment: ok. So we are using the Angular service rather than the RecursionHelper function?

Comment: Yes, we are doing it just to render the directive itself.  That should trigger directives inner methods, and `RecursionHelper,compile()` in particular.